# Why is the click event triggered multiple times after just one click?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, addeventlistener, fetch-api

I would really appreciate some help with this code I have been stuck on for a while.

My aim with this is to create a feedback for clicking an answer (multiple choice) for a simple quiz question and then it calls the function apiQuestion() to move on to the next question.

How I have attempted this is by adding an if else statement where the condition compares the clicked answer with the correct answer data inside a click event listener. It is within the scope of a fetch promise.

The problem is that after the first initial click, the click event is increasingly repeated for every subsequent event.

Again, I would greatly appreciate the help!

```
function apiQuestion() {
    fetch(`https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=39&category=31&type=multiple`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(rawData => {
        let quizData = shuffle(rawData.results);
        let question = quizData[0].question;
        let correctAnswer = quizData[0].correct_answer;
        let incorrectAnswers = quizData[0].incorrect_answers;

        quizQuestion.innerHTML = question;

        answers.forEach(answer => {
            answer.innerHTML = incorrectAnswers.shift() || correctAnswer;
        });

        console.log("Correct answer: " + correctAnswer);

        answers.forEach(answer => {
            answer.addEventListener('click', clickFeedback = (e) => {
                answer.removeEventListener('click', clickFeedback)
                let clickedItem = e.target.innerHTML;
                if (clickedItem == correctAnswer) {
                    console.log("CORRECT!");
                } else {
                    console.log("INCORRECT!");
                }
                apiQuestion();
                return;
            })
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    });
};
```

Comment: Though naming an arrow function like this is a bit odd, there's nothing in the example code which would cause an event listener to run multiple times. What happens in `apiQuestion` function?

Comment: try inspecting if the answer object doesn't have a child who is inheriting the click event.

Comment: You could also try replacing the explicit removeEventListener by adding the optional options object as the third parameter of the addEventListener function. In your case:
` answer.addEventListener('click', clickFeedback = (e) => {...}, {once: true, capture: true});`
For more information take a look at the mdn page: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: Wait! The event is never removed. You're creating an implicit global when attaching the event. On every round of the iteration, a new function is created, and `clickFeedback` refers to the latest created function when the button is clicked. Assign the handler function into a variable or use a declared function instead of creating an anonymous function on every round of the iteration. Additionally, there has to be some code somewhere calling this loop again.

Comment: After your edit the problem shows up clearly. Every click on the buttons adds a new event, and executing the extra events is adding more events. Declare `clickFeedback` function outside of `apiQuestion`, that way the same function is kept in the memory, and `clickFeedback` refers to that function and the event can be removed. This is a variation of the classic [Closures inside loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) problem.

Comment: I am complete newbie! I think I just dug myself deep into the hole of loops on loops on loops. @Teemu I'll give that a go, I think I just had too much code within ```apiQuestion```

Comment: I just figured it out. I refactored the code and used the jquery event listener with the method unbind() to remove the click that was bound to dom element. This will work for now!